# Linq to CRM - Invalid operation exception

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-4, invalidoperationexception

I'm using a LINQ to CRM from Advanced Developer Extension for MS CRM 4.0. It works fine with direct queries. But I've got a problem when query looks like this:

```
var connectionString = @"User ID=u; Password=p; Authentication Type=AD; Server=http://crm:5555/UO";
var connection = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
var dataContext = new CrmDataContext(connection);

var data = from u in dataContext.Accounts
           select new 
           {  
              Id = u.AccountID,
              Name = u.AccountName,
           };

var r = from n in data
        where n.Name.StartsWith("test")
        select new 
        { 
           Id = n.Id 
        };

r.Dump();
```

it throws an InvalidOperationException "Cannot determine the attribute name."
It's fine when a condition is directly in first query:

```
var data = from n in dataContext.Accounts
           where n.AccountName.StartsWith("test")
           select new 
           {  
              Id = n.AccountID,
              Name = n.AccountName,
           };
```

I cannot find any useful information about this kind of error. Is it a bug in Xrm Linq Provider? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try eager loading the initial query with a ToList() so the latter query over your anonymous type is then evaluated locally.  I get this is far from ideal if you have a lot of accounts but it'll prove the point.  You essentially have a solution anyway in the last statement.

This is because the first query isn't executed at all until you call .Dump() at which point the entire expression **including the second query** is evaluated as one (deferred execution) by the provider which then looks for an attribute of Name.